# How to sync my animateMotion with my CSS animation?

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I did not expect that, the goal would be to have the square make the path disappear. Both of my animation have a duration of 5s but they do not tie in.
I am new to svg animation so I did not find the solution to make it yet.

Any idea how I can make it ?

```js
// Example class component
class Svg extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
                <path className="path" id="motionPath" d="M404.88 470.22V79.69c-.2-19-14.21-33-17.52-36.19s-16.77-15.19-34.7-15.45h-1.11c-28.65.35-59.55-.12-319.52 0H28" stroke="#000" strokeWidth="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"></path>
                <rect id="circle" x="-25" y="-25" rx="15" ry="15" width="50" height="50"></rect>

                <animateMotion id="forward"
                    xlinkHref="#circle"
                    dur="5s"
                    fill="freeze"
                    keyPoints="1;0"
                    keyTimes="0;1"
                    calcMode="linear">
                    <mpath xlinkHref="#motionPath"></mpath>
                </animateMotion>
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Svg />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.path {
        stroke-dasharray: 1000;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        animation: dash 5s linear reverse;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
      }
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using one SMIL and one CSS animations do both SMIL.

Also you are animating for a path length of 1000 when the path length is 795.3

Yet another idea: you need to reverse the css animation because your initial stroke-dashoffset: 1000; Use an initial value of 0 and animate it to maxim length (795.3 - in my demo), Now you don't need to reverse it anymore,

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
                <path class="path" id="motionPath" d="M404.88,470.22v-390.53c-0.2,-19,-14.21,-33,-17.52,-36.19s-16.77,-15.19,-34.7,-15.45h-1.11c-28.65,0.35,-59.55,-0.12,-319.52,0h-4.03" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="795.30" stroke-dashoffset="0">
                  <animate
                    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
                    from="0" to="795.30"
                    dur="5s"
                    fill="freeze"
                    begin="0"/>
                </path>
                <rect id="circle" x="-25" y="-25" rx="15" ry="15" width="50" height="50">

                <animateMotion id="forward"
                    dur="5s"
                    fill="freeze"
                    keyPoints="1;0"
                    keyTimes="0;1"
                    calcMode="linear"
                    begin="0">
                    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"></mpath>
                </animateMotion>
                  
                  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Example class component
class Svg extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
                <path className="path" id="motionPath" d="M404.88 470.22V79.69c-.2-19-14.21-33-17.52-36.19s-16.77-15.19-34.7-15.45h-1.11c-28.65.35-59.55-.12-319.52 0H28" stroke="#000" strokeWidth="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"></path>
                <rect id="circle" x="-25" y="-25" rx="15" ry="15" width="50" height="50"></rect>

                <animateMotion id="forward"
                    xlinkHref="#circle"
                    dur="5s"
                    fill="freeze"
                    keyPoints="1;0"
                    keyTimes="0;1"
                    calcMode="linear">
                    <mpath xlinkHref="#motionPath"></mpath>
                </animateMotion>
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Svg />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.path {
        stroke-dasharray: 1000;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        animation: dash 5s linear reverse;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 200;
          }
      }
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I can't problem but you can use 200ms on your dash animation stroke-dashoffset. That will help you to fix the problem. And I will try to find where is the issue.